# Is it a good practice to group common functions into a single class?

Tags: php, static

I'm developing a system which I had to re-design once from procedural ajax files to ajax files that calls OOP classes.

In the first time I developed classes, each with a method that do the same thing as the ajax files did in a procedural way but with other methods that could be helpful anytime I just wanted to re-call them.

Then I had a problem: I started using inheritance, till the point I realized that if I needed two or more classes then it would be a completely disaster. How am I fixing? I'm creating static classes that contains the common functions I could need, and then I call them from the ajax classes with a single method in a static way. Here is an example of a static class I just created:

Static class:

```
<?php

    class InstitutionFunctions
    {
        public static $Statement;

        public static function InstitutionExists($InstitutionId = -1)
        {
            self :: $Statement->prepare('SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM institutions WHERE Id = ?');
            self :: $Statement->bind_param('i', $InstitutionId);
            self :: $Statement->bind_result($InstitutionCount);
            self :: $Statement->execute();
            self :: $Statement->fetch();

            if($InstitutionCount > 0)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public static function BlockInstitutionOnly($InstitutionId = -1, $BlockValue = 1)
        {
            self :: $Statement->prepare('UPDATE institutions SET Blocked = ? WHERE Id = ?');
            self :: $Statement->bind_param('ii', $BlockValue, $InstitutionId);
            self :: $Statement->execute();
        }

        public static function BlockInstitutionStudents($InstitutionId = -1, $BlockValue = 1)
        {
            self :: $Statement->prepare('UPDATE classroom SET Blocked = ? WHERE Institution = ? AND Rank = '. STUDENT);
            self :: $Statement->bind_param('ii', $BlockValue, $InstitutionId);
            self :: $Statement->execute();
        }

        public static function Create($InstitutionName = '')
        {
            self :: $Statement->prepare('INSERT INTO institutions (Name) VALUES (?)');
            self :: $Statement->bind_param('s', $InstitutionName);
            self :: $Statement->execute();
        }

        public static function GetInstitutionIdByName($InstitutionName = '')
        {
            self :: $Statement->prepare('SELECT Id FROM institutions WHERE Name = ?');
            self :: $Statement->bind_param('s', $InstitutionName);
            self :: $Statement->bind_result($InstitutionId);
            self :: $Statement->execute();
            self :: $Statement->fetch();

            return $InstitutionId;
        }

        public static function InstitutionHasAssignments($InstitutionId = -1)
        {
            self :: $Statement->prepare('SELECT COUNT(Institution) FROM assignments WHERE Institution = ?');
            self :: $Statement->bind_param('i', $InstitutionId);
            self :: $Statement->bind_result($AssignmentCount);
            self :: $Statement->execute();
            self :: $Statement->fetch();

            if($AssignmentCount > 0)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public static function Delete($InstitutionId = -1)
        {
            self :: $Statement->prepare('DELETE FROM institutions WHERE Id = ?');
            self :: $Statement->bind_param('i', $InstitutionId);
            self :: $Statement->execute();
        }

        public static function GetInstitutionBlockValue($InstitutionId = -1)
        {
            self :: $Statement->prepare('SELECT Blocked FROM institutions WHERE Id = ?');
            self :: $Statement->bind_param('i', $InstitutionId);
            self :: $Statement->bind_result($BlockValue);
            self :: $Statement->execute();
            self :: $Statement->fetch();

            return $BlockValue;
        }
    }

?>
```

And then the ajax class calls it like this:

```
<?php

    class BlockInstitution
    {
        public $User;
        public $InstitutionId;
        public $BlockValue;
        public $Error;
        public $ErrorN;

        public function __construct($User, $InstitutionId = -1, $BlockValue = '1')
        {
            $this->User = $User;
            $this->InstitutionId = $InstitutionId;
            $this->BlockValue = $BlockValue;
        }

        public function ValidateAndBlock()
        {
            if(!$this->User->SessionExist)
            {
                $this->Error = 'El proceso se cancel&oacute; porque tu sesi&oacute;n ha sido cerrada.';
                $this->ErrorN = 1;

                return false;
            }

            if($this->User->Session['Rank'] != ADMIN)
            {
                $this->Error = 'No est&aacute;s autorizado para realizar esta acci&oacute;n.';
                $this->ErrorN = 2;

                return false;
            }

            if(!InstitutionFunctions :: InstitutionExists($this->InstitutionId))
            {
                $this->Error = 'Esta instituci&oacute;n no existe.';
                $this->ErrorN = 3;

                return false;
            }

            InstitutionFunctions :: BlockInstitutionOnly($this->InstitutionId, $this->BlockValue);
            InstitutionFunctions :: BlockInstitutionStudents($this->InstitutionId, $this->BlockValue);

            $this->Error = '';
            $this->ErrorN = -1;

            return true;
        }
    }

?>
```

I would like to know if I'm doing this is in a right way, I readed somewhere that static methods aren't recommended dude that they are hard to test, I want to know if this is my case too.

Otherwise, Would be better if I just seperate them into single functions? I know that when I include the static class uses a bit more of CPU, but I'm saving memory because I'm not creating any instance.

I'm just trying to look for a better organized way to work, this is one of the reasons of why I like to work with OOP instead of use procedural, but as we well know, OOP can take more CPU / memory. Thank's I'll be waiting for your opinions!

Comment: "but as we well know, OOP can take more CPU / memory" --- facepalm. Assembly consumes less CPU/RAM - use it instead then.

Comment: hahahaha nice quote! Yeah, you're so right, after all they're just little mss, and it is better to have a more control of the system itself.

Comment: Rule #4 of StackOverflow: if OP says "as we well know", we actually don't.

Comment: All-static-classes have nothing to do with OOP. If you want to have namespace function, then you should be using php namespaces, instead of pretending that you are writing object oriented code.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Neo. Try to construct your questions so it doesn't take someone an hour to figure out what you're up to, and we'll be able to give you better advice. Sounds like your question should be "I'm coding functions that do X, and they have Y in common, so what's the best way to organize them?" Trying to figure out X and Y from (badly designed) code is not something you'll get lots of takers for. Can you fill us in?

Comment: Static methods actually run much faster than instance methods in PHP, so that should not be a problem. That being said, if you want a bunch of functions/procedures, create a bunch of functions/procedures in a namespace rather than a dummy class containing only static methods.

Comment: Before nothing, thank's for answering, I just wanted to know if creating a static class was a good idea, my dear friends tereško and Fabien touched the point I want to clear, are static functions recommended for this? their answer was "Yes it could be good, but namespaces are more decent", that is want I wanted to know, I never worked with namespaces before, but it's time to take an eye on it. I know my question was not really relevant, sorry if it was hard to understand and the answers where so obvious, I was a bit confused and I'll try to be clear next time. =)

Comment: I think you somewhat misread those comments :)